# How to generate Typescript-Client with openapi-typescript-codegen?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, npm-scripts

When i install [openapi-typescript-codegen](https://github.com/ferdikoomen/openapi-typescript-codegen) 
as described in the readme with `$ npm install openapi-typescript-codegen --save-dev`
it generates a package-lock.json but no package.json and no tsconfig.json. Even if i maually create the package.json and run `npm run generate-client` it does not work. And throws this  log at me:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'generate-client' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v10.19.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pregenerate-client',
4 verbose run-script   'generate-client',
4 verbose run-script   'postgenerate-client' ]
5 info lifecycle frontend-api-client@1.0.0~pregenerate-client: frontend-api-client@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle frontend-api-client@1.0.0~generate-client: frontend-api-client@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle frontend-api-client@1.0.0~generate-client: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle frontend-api-client@1.0.0~generate-client: PATH: /usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/tom/Arbeit/Frontend-API-Client/node_modules/.bin:/home/tom/.local/bin:/opt/ros/foxy/bin:/home/tom/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle frontend-api-client@1.0.0~generate-client: CWD: /home/tom/Arbeit/Frontend-API-Client
10 silly lifecycle frontend-api-client@1.0.0~generate-client: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'openapi --input http://0.0.0.0:8000/openapi.json --output ./src/client --client axios' ]
11 silly lifecycle frontend-api-client@1.0.0~generate-client: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle frontend-api-client@1.0.0~generate-client: Failed to exec generate-client script
13 verbose stack Error: frontend-api-client@1.0.0 generate-client: `openapi --input http://0.0.0.0:8000/openapi.json --output ./src/client --client axios`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid frontend-api-client@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/tom/Arbeit/Frontend-API-Client
16 verbose Linux 5.13.0-40-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "generate-client"
18 verbose node v10.19.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error frontend-api-client@1.0.0 generate-client: `openapi --input http://0.0.0.0:8000/openapi.json --output ./src/client --client axios`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the frontend-api-client@1.0.0 generate-client script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Im currently trying to use the tutorial from [FastAPI Generate Clients](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/generate-clients/).
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try to verify that your **openapi.json** is a valid OpenAPI specification (you can use the [online swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io) for that). Also your node and npm versions seem to be quite old.

Comment: It indeed was the old npm version causing the trouble. Thank you kind stranger

Answer (score 0):

NPM version was to old, in the end that was the only issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).